# Converting each row of a dataframe into a string and assigning it as a column to another dataset in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe, data-conversion

I have a dataset:

```
id   name   address   phone   email
123  abc    123 abc   12345   info@abc.com
456  cbs    456 cbs   67890   info@cbs.com
758  nbc    789 nbc   11121   info@nbc.com
```

I want to create a new dataset, where it retains the first two columns (id and name) and has the third column, which will have a string that is a combination of values of address, phone and email. In other words, I need it to look like this:

```
id   name   meta_str
123  abc    '123 abc   12345   info@abc.com'
456  cbs    '456 cbs   67890   info@cbs.com'
758  nbc    '789 nbc   11121   info@nbc.com'
```

This is the code I have:

```
df_transformed = df[['id','name']]
df_meta = df[['address','phone','email']]
df_meta_str = df_meta.iloc[:].to_string(header=False, index=False)
df_transformed['meta_str'] = df_meta_str
```

But what I get is:

```
id   name   meta_str
123  abc    '123 abc   12345   info@abc.com'
456  cbs    '123 abc   12345   info@abc.com'
758  nbc    '123 abc   12345   info@abc.com'
```

I think the problem is that df_meta_str has the data in all rows combined as one big string.

What would be a way to achieve a separate string on a separate row?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `str concatenation`:

```
df['meta_str'] = df.address + ' ' + df.phone.astype(str) + ' ' + df.email 

df.drop(['address','phone','email'], 1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
id   name   meta_str
123  abc    123 abc 12345 info@abc.com
456  cbs    456 cbs 67890 info@cbs.com
758  nbc    789 nbc 11121 info@nbc.com
```

**OR**

use `df.apply` method:

```
df['meta_str'] = df[['address','phone','email']].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do

```
df['meta_str']=df.loc[:,'address':].astype(str).agg(' '.join,1)
0    123abc 12345 info@abc.com
1    456cbs 67890 info@cbs.com
2    789nbc 11121 info@nbc.com
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.Series.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) here.

```
df['meta_str'] = df['address'].str.cat(df[['phone','email']].astype(str),sep=' ')
df.drop(columns='address')

   id   name   meta_str
0  123  abc    123 abc 12345 info@abc.com
1  456  cbs    456 cbs 67890 info@cbs.com
2  758  nbc    789 nbc 11121 info@nbc.com
```